# How to simplify the coding pattern and repetition

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way to simplify the repeating code by using the for-loop function?

```
def reshape_matrix(value1, value2, value3):
    renew_value1 = np.reshape(value1, (np.size(value1), 1), order='C')
    renew_value2 = np.reshape(value2, (np.size(value2), 1), order='C')
    renew_value3 = np.reshape(value3, (np.size(value3), 1), order='C')
    return renew_value1, renew_value2, renew_value3

a, b, c = reshape_matrix(A[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]], B[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]], C[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
```

Comment: What is `value1, value2, value3`, how are you calling the functions ?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I call the functions by using 'a, b, c = reshape_matrix(Value1, Value2, Value3,)'

Comment: @wentonglu I think DeveshKumarSingh is asking what are the values, value1, value2 and value3, as well as how you are calling the function.

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh, Thank you for asking. the value1, value2, and value3 are matrix. I am calling the function by using a, b, c = reshape_matrix(Value1, Value2, Value3) Syntax

Comment: Could you add how those look like, a sample in the question itself?

Comment: @MatthewGadsden Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Will the dimension always be `1x3` like you have, or can they be like `3x3` for eg

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh the dimension always like 3x3.  if reshape the matrix, the matrix will become 9x1

Comment: I mean the individual dimension of this, `[1,2,3]`, will always be `1x3`, or can this be bigger like `3x3` also `a, b, c = reshape_matrix(A[1,2,3], B[1,2,3], C[1,2,3])` is a syntax error

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh The code has been modified, Could you please check it.   Thank you for point the issue out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the matrix is always `3x3` and you want to convert to a `9x1` array, you can pass the dimensions to `reshape` directly

```
import numpy as np

def reshape_matrix(*values):

    return [np.reshape(item, (9,1)) for item in values]

x = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]])

a, b, c = reshape_matrix(x,x,x)
print(a, b, c)
```

The output will be

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]] [[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]] [[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]]
```

Comment: The print result quite well.  But, could you please make the `a, b, c = reshape_matrix([x,x,x])` works?  Then `print(a, b, c)`.  Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Wow, Now I might know how the `(*values)` works, Thank you so much.  You are so nice.

Answer (score 3):

If there are always only three parameters it isn't worth to optimize. If not:

```
def reshape_matrix(*values):
    return tuple(np.reshape(v, (np.size(v), 1), order='C') for v in values)
```

Where shorter does not always mean to be better, especially not better understandable/readable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

A way to simplify the repeating code would be to use a for-loop like you said.
However if there are only at a max 3 values then there is no reason to change the function you currently use.

If using more than 3 values then use something like this

```py
def reshape_matrix(*values):
    new_vals = ()
    for value in values:
        new_vals += (np.reshape(value, (np.size(value), 1),)
    return new_vals
```